# Tracking resources and Unload them while not neccecary

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have been trying to design a system in Java where I can track resources like Images and Audio files loaded from disk and unloading them when there are no references to it.

In C++ I could override the delete operator so I could decrement the reference.
But Java works with automatic garbage collection which destroys an object when it has no references.

Because I keep track of all the resources in my resourcemanager, the reference to the object will never be null, thus the resources will never be unloaded if they are not needed.

Is there a way to keep track of the objects while at the same time deleting them while they have no references from entities?

I have heard a deconstructor is not safe so that's also not an option

Comment: Managed GC langauges have non-deterministic destruction, so you can't really tie the closing of a resource to the destruction of an object.  It's one of the things I miss most from C++ when Java/C# programming.

Comment: There's no automatic way. You must implement some sort of refcounting. Everything that uses a resource will have to call `acquire` at the start and `release` in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use WeakRefence in your resourcemanager, e.g. a WeakHashMap.

You can find a good explanation of WeakReferences (and other references e.g. Softreference)  here: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Simple said:
A weak reference is a reference that does not to force the object to stay in memory. If there is no strong reference to the object, but you still have the weak reference in your resourcemanager, the object is still eliglible for garbage collection and can be deleted by the garbage collector.

Comment: WeakRef is still not solving timely disposal. It couples resource lifetime to the object lifetime, thus opening the door for a resource leak.

Comment: This is for a different use case where for example you might want to hold on to an object reference for caching purposes but not prevent GC.  It doesn't help with resource managment in the scenario the OP describes.

Comment: @Pablo - A weak reference can only be used while there happen to be other references to the object (once all those references have gone the WR can't be used for anything such as closing resources).  Additionally in the scenario described, you want timely closing of resources, not when a GC occurs which could be days after the object loses it's last reference.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik: I don#t think timely disposal is needed in the scenario the OP described. The GC will run as soon as there is memory needed and will dispose the object if there is no strong reference to it.

Comment: @Polygnome - There's a difference between memory and resources (such as file handles which the OP does mention).  It's possible to write a program which constantly leaks file handles but never uses much heap, and therefore never triggers garbage collection.  GC= great for memory management but terrible for resource management.

Comment: I personally had an SWT handle leak precisely in this scenario. When you've got hundreds of MB heap but only 64K handles to a UI resource, you're soon going to feel the difference between resource management and memory management.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussion! But it seems there is no automatic way? I mean there's not really another choice then calling dispose or release manually?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the users of the resources to manually `dispose` the resources they use when they are finished with them, something like the `close()` method in `java.io` package.

Inside suche `dispose` method you can decrement a counter and when zero is reachead you explicitly release the underlying resource.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 does have a neat way of permitting scope based [automatic resource management](http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/java-7-awesome-aspect-automatic-resource-management/) where you tie the closing of a resource to the closing a paticular program scope.  However, as I understand things, object based resource management (which you appear to be describing) is not possible due to the non-deterministic nature of Java object destruction.

For more complex scenarios where resource closure must occur outside the original scope in which the resources were opened (on another thread for example or after recieving an event), manual closure must be performed.  Ref counting implementations (common to C++) are sadly not possible.